# Proving monotonic decreasing of general term: $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{n^2-1}{n^3-1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

I have got the following series -

> $$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{n^2-1}{n^3-1} $$

I know that this an alternating series which converge - but got confused on how to prove this the general term series monotonic decreasing.

Should I use the derivate of it? or proving by $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ as my teacher did ? and when should i choose each method?

Comment: Hint: $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$ and $n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$.

Comment: Alright , but still after doing in i should proof the monotonic formally - which method should i prefer?

Comment: I would prefer the derivative, but for exams you might need to do it using the ratio.So try both. There is also the difference test.

Comment: As written, your series is divergent. You should sum over $n\geq 2$, not $k\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Should I use the derivate of it? or proving by $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ as my teacher did ?*

You may use standard properties of precalculus, from
$$
n+1\geq n
$$ you get
$$
(n+1)^2+(n+1)+1\geq n^2+n+1
$$ giving, for $n\geq1$,

> $$
> \frac1{(n+1)^2+(n+1)+1}\leq \frac1{n^2+n+1}.
> $$

Comment: Thanks , so just to verify - this means the general term is smaller than 1 for all  $n\geq1$ ?

Comment: @GeorgeB Yes and it tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.